# I am getting Error 500: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-07-18 16:57:22.0"

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

```
String date = "2013-07-18 16:57:22.0";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mm:SSSS.FF6");
Date dateTime=format.parse(date);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(format.getTimeZone());
calendar.setTime(dateTime);
```

and i am getting error

Error 500: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-07-18 16:57:22.0"

Answer (score 3):

Try with this: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"`

Take a look: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm unsure what the `HH24` part of your format is meant to do: `HH` already means you need the hour of the day in 24 hours format.

By the same token, what is `FF6` bit supposed to achieve? According to the documentation, `F` is the day of the week in month, is there a particular reason for you to put that after your seconds? What is the `6` part meant to do?

`SSSS` is a bit odd as well - you want the milliseconds on a 4 digits number (the maximum value is 999, isn't it?), but not the seconds?

Try and build your format logically from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) - I believe you'll end up with something very similar to what @davioooh is suggesting.

Comment: I'm glad I'm getting all these upvotes, but why am I getting more than @davioooh who provided an actual working answer? :)

Comment: hi Nicolas knw i got it i hd md these changes and nw it is workin fine                                                       DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date dateTime=format.parse(date);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(format.getTimeZone());
calendar.setTime(dateTime);
    DateFormat dff = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    dff.format(calendar.getTime());